# Copying files from multiple directories in msbuild

Tags: msbuild

I have following directories (for example)

```
./dirA/file1
./dirA/dir/file2
./dirB/file3
./dirB/dir/file4
./dirC/file5
```

And I want to have them copied to something different, like:

```
./dirA_renamed/file1
./dirA_renamed/dir/file2
./dirB_renamed_differently/file3
./dirB_renamed_differently/dir/file4
./dirC_renam/file5
```

The list of directories and their new names is something that does not change very often, but I'd like to use only one `Copy`.

I tried following:

```
<ItemGroup>
 <ToCopy Include=".\dirA">
  <OutputDirName>dirA_renamed</OutputDirName>
 </ToCopy>
 <ToCopy Include=".\dirB">
  <OutputDirName>dirB_renamed_differently</OutputDirName>
 </ToCopy>
 <ToCopy Include=".\dirC">
  <OutputDirName>dirC_renam</OutputDirName>
 </ToCopy>
</ItemGroup>
```

......

```
<CreateItem Include="%(ToCopy.Directory)\**\*.*">
 <Output TaskParameter="Include" ItemName="FilesToCopy" />
</CreateItem>

<Copy SourceFiles="@(FilesToCopy)" DestinationFolder="@(FilesToCopy->'%(OutputDirName)')" />
```

But nothing happens. If I output `FilesToCopy`, it is empty. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hard coded way is the one I know, but I know that you can use parameters, I just haven't figure it out completely yet, to give you a working sample.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003"
            ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Build">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <RootDir>C:\DevDir</RootDir>
    <SourceA>dirA</SourceA>
    <SourceB>dirB</SourceB>
    <SourceC>dirC</SourceC>
    <RenameA>dirA_renamed</RenameA>
    <RenameB>dirB_renamed_differently</RenameB>
    <RenameC>dirC_renam</RenameC>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <Target Name="CopyDirTest" >

    <ItemGroup>
      <SourceDirA Include="$(RootDir)$(SourceA)\"/>
      <SourceDirB Include="$(RootDir)$(SourceB)\" />
      <SourceDirC Include="$(RootDir)$(SourceC)\" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
      <SourceAFiles Include="$(RootDir)$(SourceA)\**\*.*"  />
      <SourceBFiles Include="$(RootDir)$(SourceB)\**\*.*" />
      <SourceCFiles Include="$(RootDir)$(SourceC)\**\*.*" />
      <SourceAllFiles Include="@(SourceAFiles);@(SourceBFiles);@(SourceCFiles)" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <CreateItem Include="@(SourceAFiles->Replace($(SourceA), $(RenameA)))">
      <Output TaskParameter="Include" ItemName="RenamedSourceA" />
    </CreateItem>

    <CreateItem Include="@(SourceBFiles->Replace($(SourceB), $(RenameB)))">
      <Output TaskParameter="Include" ItemName="RenamedSourceB" />
    </CreateItem>    

    <CreateItem Include="@(SourceCFiles->Replace($(SourceC), $(RenameC)))">
      <Output TaskParameter="Include" ItemName="RenamedSourceC" />
    </CreateItem>

    <ItemGroup>
      <RenamedAllFiles Include="@(RenamedSourceA);@(RenamedSourceB);@(RenamedSourceC)" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <Message Text="%(SourceAllFiles.Identity)" Importance="high" />
    <Message Text="%(RenamedAllFiles.Identity)" Importance="high" />

    <Copy SourceFiles="@(SourceAllFiles)" DestinationFiles="@(RenamedAllFiles)" />
  </Target>

</Project>
```